# Creating a modified symlog scale function that is symmetric around 1 (10^0) instead of 0

Tags: logarithms, symmetric-functions

I want to create a symlog function that is symmetric around 1 (10^0) instead of 0. The range of output values for the function will be positive: [10^-6 - 10^6] and the input values will be from a linear range (e.g., 0 - 1000).

The expected scale should be like this:

[image: sym-log-scale-visually]

In other words, the scale ticks on the left of the mid-point (10^0 = 1; denoted as "equal" in the above image) should be a mirror image of the right of 1.

To further explain, here is a visualization of a traditional symlog plot that is symmetric around 0:
[image: symlog-traditional-plot]
This is the paper that proposed this scale: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/70d5/3d9f448e6f2c10bd87a4a058be64f5af7dbc.pdf

The modification that I need is to be symmetric around 1 (10^0).

I am not very good at math especially log math. Having a hard time figuring this out. Could someone provide some insights as to how best to do it?

Comment: Make the mathematical question clearer and get rid of anything unnecessary to the question. People don't really want to read through your code. From skimming your question, it's not immediately clear what you are asking. If you want to get an answer, it probably should be.

Comment: Updated text to remove all the unnecessary details. Let me know if its still unclear.